# bitmap set in the image view is not getting fill parent

Tags: android

I have compressed the image using this:

```
      private Bitmap decodeFile(InputStream is){
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=100;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
    }
```

I am setting this bitmap in an image view but it leaves some space on top and bottom.

I tried this:

```
    img.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

but of no use.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may solve the issue.

```
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this, in your activity,

```
mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

or in your layout,

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```